# use apply or for loop for arrays in R

Tags: r, loops

I do have a function which generates as a result of execution a 3 dim array. I would need to have all individual matrixes saved when the function is executed several times.

So during the first execution the output is an array with say dim 10,20,30. Then I would like to save each matrix for 1:10 in the 1 dim. Then the function is executed again giving rise to a new array dim 10,20,30 and the loop (or apply) shall then cycle through 1:10 again and save all matrixes. I initially tried to index with [[]] in a for loop but then it is saved as list and the arrays become unusable. I woudl really appreciate any help even if it is not a complete solution. I really don't know how to do that

Comment: The result that was in list form was probably perfectly usable, but you just didn't know how to do it. You should post your code and then say what you want done.

Comment: What you want is to save the 2D matrix for each third dimension of the 3D array in a list? I.e. `arr = array(1:21, c(2,2,3))` ; `arr` ; `apply(arr, 3, list)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `abind` function, in the `abind` library. I'm not sure if you can specify how apply combines things, so instead we're going to use `foreach` from the `foreach` package.

So this will allow you to combine your two-dimensional matrices into three dimensional arrays:

```
library(abind)
library(foreach)

# Helper function, we want to bind along the third dimension?
abind3 <- function(...) { abind(along = 3, ...) }

result <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine=abind3) %do% {
  # Generate each matrix here
  matrix(i, 10, 10)
}
```

You can then store each of these in a list if you want to execute multiple times, when wrapping with a for loop/lapply/foreach.

Note the syntactic differences in `foreach` from `for`: First, `i = 1:10` instead of `i in 1:10`, second the `%do%`. This is important if you're nesting foreach loops:

```
foreach(i = 1:10) %:% 
  foreach(j = 1:10) %do% {
   # do thing
}
```

Comment: I suppose i did not really make this clear but I already have a 3dim array as an output of the function. The function is executed like 20 times and in each run I want to save the array that is put out by the function as array (and then save all the matrixes (say 30) that make up the array seperately for each of the 20 trials so that I end up with 20 times 30 matrixes

Comment: You should just be able to run `lapply(1:20, yourFunction)` then

Comment: the problem is i needot to get an element from this function(which is then the array I was talking about) if i type lapply(1:20 myfunc$element) there is an error that Myfunc$element is not a function, character or symbol